# Creating an object that works with NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject, nsjsonserialization

At the moment in order to use this function I'm "converting" my object into a dictionary. i.e. the property names become the keys and the property values become the values.

Is there a way to properly do this so that an object will work with this function?

i.e. similar to `encodeWithCoder` and `initWithCoder` for use with `NSUserDefaults`.

I'd like to do ...

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myObject options:0 error:nil];
```

at the moment I do something like...

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[myObject dictionaryRepresentation] options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: No, because `NSJSONSerialization` hasn't a clue about foreign classes. Why isn't the current approach good? It seems rather good/simple/elegant.

Comment: It works I just wondered if there was another way. Seemed a bit like overkill to convert to dictionary and then to data, wondered if I could cut out the middle step.

Comment: I can't suddenly think about one, unfortunately.

Comment: There are 3rd-party schemes that translate between JSON and user objects, using a set of rules.  I think most are for Java, but you could always get the source for one and transliterate to Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look. Prob easier to keep doing my dictionary conversion :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [JSONCoding](https://github.com/ontometrics/JSONCoding), which builds on NSJSONSerialization with an NSCoding interface.